# Javascript Garbage Collection Related

Tags: javascript

In the code below, does `aObj` remain in memory after garbage collection? And what is the easiest way I can test and see this?

```
var a = function(arg) {
    this.argument = arg;    
}

var aObj = new a({ prop1: 1, prop2: 2 });    
var b = aObj.argument;    
aObj = null;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, it does not. After the `aObj = null` line, there are no remaining references to the object it used to contain. *It* has a reference to `argument`, but `argument` doesn't have a reference to *it*, and so after you've released the only reference to the object (in `aObj`), the object is eligible for garbage collection.

Let's stop the world just **before** the `aObj = null` line and see what's in memory (leaving out some details):

```
          +−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−+
a−−−−−−−−>|  (function)   |
          +−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−+
          | (...)         |        +−−−−−−−−−−+
          | prototype     |−−−−+−−>| (object) |
          +−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−+    |   +−−−−−−−−−−+
                               |   | (...)    |
                               |   +−−−−−−−−−−+
                               |
          +−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−+    |
      +−−>|   (object)    |    |
      |   +−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−+    |
      |   | [[Prototype]] |−−−−+   +−−−−−−−−−−+
      |   | argument      |−−−−+−−>| (object) |
      |   +−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−+    |   +−−−−−−−−−−+
      |                        |   | prop1: 1 |
aObj−−+                        |   | prop2: 2 |
                               |   +−−−−−−−−−−+
b−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−+
```

Now, we do the `aObj = null` line, and get:

```
          +−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−+
a−−−−−−−−>|  (function)   |
          +−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−+
          | (...)         |        +−−−−−−−−−−+
          | prototype     |−−−−+−−>| (object) |
          +−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−+    |   +−−−−−−−−−−+
                               |   | (...)    |
                               |   +−−−−−−−−−−+
                               |
          +−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−+    |
          |   (object)    |    |
          +−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−+    |
          | [[Prototype]] |−−−−+   +−−−−−−−−−−+
          | argument      |−−−−+−−>| (object) |
          +−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−+    |   +−−−−−−−−−−+
                               |   | prop1: 1 |
aObj: null                     |   | prop2: 2 |
                               |   +−−−−−−−−−−+
b−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−+
```

As you can see, nothing has a reference to that object anymore.

> And what is the easiest way I can test and see this?

Chrome has a pretty advanced memory profiler which can, amongst other things, show you the number of objects from a given constructor that are still in memory. More on [their dev tools site here](https://developer.chrome.com/devtools/docs/heap-profiling).